# Connectivity via a Field Gateway with IoT Central

Tags: azure, azure-iot-central

I am building an IoT Solution based on non programmable devices. I can just configure a host where they can connect to send data and receive commands.

Now, supposed that I know the messaging protocol of the device, I would like to build a field gateway to apply protocol and identity translation with the IoT Hub behind IoT Central.
Is that doable ? If yes, may you drive me to the solution please ?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIk, this scenario is not implemented yet. Please provide your feedback on the [UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/911455-azure-iot-central/suggestions/37799383-support-modules-from-iot-hub-along-with-multipl).
All the feedback you share in these forums will be monitored and reviewed by the Microsoft engineering teams responsible for building Azure.

Reference: [How to create IoT edge device on IoT central?](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/14035)